# How to emit events from Solana native rust smart contract?

Tags: solana-program

I want to emit event from the native rust solana smart contract. And how to add listener to listen all upcoming events for specific smart contract.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anchor rust code snippet:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

#[program]
pub fn initialize(_ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
    emit!(MyEvent {
        err_msg_code: 100
    });
    Ok(())
}

#[event]
pub struct MyEvent {
    pub err_msg_code: u32,
}
```

Comment: What happens exactly when a event gets triggered? For instance in your example would `MyEvent` struct be displayed in `logMessages` within the corresponding transaction?

Comment: @PeterSchwarz Event is emitted so that it can be subscribe to by the clients. And it would not display in logMessages, for that u need to use msg macro.